# How to "unsuck" a denormalized varchar column?

Tags: java, sql, h2, jooq

This is an hypothetic example; well, quite not hypothetic since I reproduced it in code:

```
public final class JooqPlayAround
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException, SQLException
    {
        final Path path = Paths.get("/tmp/meh");

        if (Files.exists(path))
            // see https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-more
            MoreFiles.deleteRecursive(path, RecursionMode.KEEP_GOING);

        Files.createDirectories(path);
        final Path dbpath = path.resolve("foo");

        final String db = "jdbc:h2:" + dbpath.toAbsolutePath();
        final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(db, "sa", "");
        final DSLContext jooq = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.H2);

        //jooq.dropTableIfExists("bad").execute();
        final CreateTableColumnStep step = jooq.createTable("bad")
            .column("f1", SQLDataType.INTEGER.nullable(false))
            .column("f2", SQLDataType.INTEGER.nullable(false))
            .column("fuckedup", SQLDataType.VARCHAR.length(20).nullable(false));

        step.execute();

        final Table<Record> table = DSL.tableByName("bad");
        final Field<Object> f1 = DSL.fieldByName("f1");
        final Field<Object> f2 = DSL.fieldByName("f2");
        final Field<Object> f3 = DSL.fieldByName("fuckedup");

        jooq.insertInto(table, f1, f2, f3)
            .values(1, 2, "hello,world")
            .execute();

        // prints "1 2" as expected
        jooq.select(f1, f2)
            .from(table)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

I have been looking at many a page and failed to achieve what I want, that is "unfsuck up" the f*ed up column; that is, I'd like to obtain this:

```
1    2    hello
1    2    world
```

I am not an SQL expert and am only used to work with properly normalized tables; this isn't one. How do I obtain the result above in SQL, knowing that I use:

- jooq 3.5.1,
- h2 as an SQL engine?

It looks to me like what is needed is a pivot of some sort, but I am unable to even split the string at the moment :/

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want to split `hellow,world` in SQL, so that the `select` query returns 2 rows instead of 1?

Comment: @Matt yes, exactly; I have "the art of SQL" which contains some tips but I have tried in vain to adapt them...

Comment: Not sure about how one would solve this in plain SQL. Your best bet is probably a user defined function (see http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions the section about *Using a Function as a Table*)